# How to add com.typesafe.sbt.* dependencies to my project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I was playing with one sbt web plugin and I wanted to reuse the code in my project. Unfortunately I wasn't even able to compile the original code in my project because of missing dependencies. These are the imports:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.{CompileProblems, LineBasedProblem}
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._
import xsbti.Severity
```

None of these could be resolved. The build fails with messages like `not found: object sbt`. I checked the original project's `build.sbt` file but there was nothing relevant in `libraryDependencies`.

I'm using Intellij Idea and the strange thing is that when I expand **External Libraries** in the Project View I can find all the required stuff under *SBT: sbt-and-plugins* (for example object `com.typesafe.sbt.web.CompileProblems` is there and I can see its definition in the class file).

It seems to me that the stuff I need is a core part of sbt but somehow it won't load to the project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is at least 2 project modules in IntelliJIDEA - one for build iteslf and one or more for projects, `sbt-and-plugins` dependency added only for build itself. Assuming that you trying to use a code (dependent on sbt)inside your project (not build) - you need to add these dependencies (from your plugin.sbt) to the libraryDependencies of your project, if you need sbt itself - you have to add sbt itself as well.

Comment: sbt jars are placed here - http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org.scala-sbt/

Comment: That makes sense. I managed to load the sbt* stuff (three last imports). To fix the first two I apparently need `sbt-js-engine` and/or `sbt-web`. Unfortunately, neither of those work when I put them to dependencies in my `build.sbt`. The refresh always ends up with `[error] sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-js-engine;1.0.2: not found`. I tried to add different repositories I found around to `resolvers` but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try `resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"` ?

Comment: I did. Btw. this particular repository doesn't even contain `sbt-js-engine` (at least I wasn't able to find it)

Comment: here they are - https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/

Comment: Sorry, still nothing. I added `https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/` to `resolvers` but no difference. The weird thing is that I use `sbt-js-engine` actively during the build process, so it gets resolved somehow... the problem is when I try to add it as a dependency to the actual project itself.

Comment: I noticed another thing: my project uses Scala 2.11 and none of the repositories contains `sbt-js-engine` for this version. I tried switching to `2.10.4` in my `build.sbt` but again... no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### short answer: [from here](https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine)

#### EDIT (3): answer:

use a custom ivy resolver:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("SBT Plugins", url("https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

libraryDependencies += ("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-js-engine" % "1.0.2")
  .extra(
    sbt.mavenint.PomExtraDependencyAttributes.SbtVersionKey -> sbtBinaryVersion.value,
    sbt.mavenint.PomExtraDependencyAttributes.ScalaVersionKey -> scalaBinaryVersion.value)
  .copy(crossVersion = CrossVersion.Disabled)
```

#### how to find plugin jars:

to figure out from where exactly sbt downloads the jars, I used this (somewhat awkward) process:

first, I wanted to see where sbt stores the file localy. so:

```
sbt "reload plugins" "show fullClasspath" | sed s/\),\ Attributed\(/\\n/g
```

and I searched the output (or you can use `grep`).

then, I deleted the file, and executed sbt again with: `reload plugins`, `update` & `last update` to see the full update log.
searching the log, I found a line saying where sbt got the plugin from.

Comment: It works! Thanks. For the completeness of the answer to my question it should be mentioned that the three latter imports required `"org.scala-sbt" % "scripted-plugin" % "0.13.5"` in my `build.sbt`.

Comment: i edited my answer. although it worked, it was totally wrong.